# Browse for directory tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, directory

I want to create a browse button with tkinter to browse for a directory that contains certain files. I am making a program that is supposed to copy files and run some controls on these files in a certain directories, but the directory can vary from time to time. The browse button will be on the start page, and you should be able to choose a directory and then click another button to run one of the controls in the program and the files of the directory will be used during the control. I have also added an entry where it should state what directory is chosen. Does anyone know how to browse for a directory and store the path of it for later use? And how to tie together an entry and the directory chosen through browsing?

My tkinter script looks something like this (work in progress):

```
from tkinter import *
import os

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
current_dir = os.getcwd()


class Gui(Tk):

 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    Tk.wm_title(self, "My controls")

    container = Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.geometry("350x500")

    self.frames = {}

    frame = StartPage(container, self)

    self.frames[StartPage] = frame

    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(StartPage)

 def show_frame(self, cont):

    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(Frame):

 def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = Label(self, text="My controls",     font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
    self.buttons()
    self.program = ""

 *#Defining the browsebutton, any suggestions on what I should do next?**

 def browsedir(self):
    from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

    Tk().withdraw()
    self.filename = askdirectory()

*#Defining the copying of the files and filepath. How to make the filepath variable?*

def runanalyze1(filepath):
  for txt in os.listdir(filepath):
    if txt.endswith('.txt'):
        copyfiles(from_path=filepath+"\\"+txt, to_path=r"C:\catalog"+"\\"+txt)

 def buttons(self):

    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    analyze1button = Button(self, text="Copyfiles", command=self.runanalyze1)
    analyze1button.place(x=50, y=150) 

    quitbutton = Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
    quitbutton.place(x=150, y=250)

    *#Creating the browse button*

    browsebutton = Button(self, text="Browse", command=self.browsedir)
    browsebutton.pack(side=BOTTOM)

   *#Creating an entry, not sure how to tie this to the browse button either.*

    e1 = Entry(self, bd=5)
    e1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    e1.insert(0, "{}".format(current_dir))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = Gui()
  app.mainloop()
```

NOTE: I have more code for the rest of the control etc., I just added what is relevant for the question. Working in Python 3.4.1. Thankful for answers!

Comment: It looks like your code is already able to let the user browse for a directory, and is saving it to a variable. Why do you need help? What is it about  your current solution that you don't like?

Comment: It does not work, the program is not able to find the directory and the files when the code is like this. So I figured there must be something I did wrong or something more I could do, but I could not seem to figure it out myself.

Comment: What do you mean by "the program is not able to  find the directory"? When you call `askdirectory`, the program doesn't do anything. It's the user that searches for and finds the directory. Are you saying that some directory isn't showing up in the dialog?

Comment: To me it looks like the browse button is there, but it is not doing anything. When I choose the directory with the files I want to run the control on through the browse button and afterwards click on the button that run the controls (including "runanalyze1" from the coding in my question) the files in the current directory are copied and controlled (the directory where I am saving my scripts) and not the directory chosen with the browse button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading through the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module. It has some interesting things on the finding of paths, you can just store these as string variables as they are absolute paths. Another useful thing is, `os.getcwd()` or `os.path.dirname(__file__)`, they give the near same thing, a path to the current directory. The first give which directory the file was executed in and the second is which directory the file is in.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it!